# How dispatch syn cause deadLock ? ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

apple say :
Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock !

but this code work fine:

```
   dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = 

dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
                        __block UIImage *image = nil;
                        dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{ 
                        /* Download the image here sync downloading */
                        });

                        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        /* Show the image to the user here on the main queue */
                        });
        });
```

although I download the image with dispatch_sync and send the block to the same queue !

Comment: It deadlocks serial queues, but it's unsurprising that it doesn't generally deadlock a concurrent queues (you wouldn't expect it to except in extreme situations). But you should never dispatch synchronously from a queue back to itself, anyway.

Comment: yes that's right, thank you for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW20) says:

> You should never call the dispatch_sync or dispatch_sync_f function
>   from a task that is executing in the same queue that you are planning
>   to pass to the function. This is particularly important for serial
>   queues, which are guaranteed to deadlock, but should also be avoided
>   for concurrent queues.

Since `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)` is **concurrent queue**, it could cause deadlock, but not always. Anyway That is strictly discouraged by Apple.